# Transport.send(message) throws Network is unreachable while trying to send the mail from my java application

Tags: jakarta-mail, sendmail

i have been working on this application that sends email from my local RHEL server.
the mail path is:
1. local server to exchange server (outlook, office365)
2. exchange server to mail related domain.

when i test my application from my local PC-WindowsXP it works fine (it sends the mail).
but when i try the same from my RHEL server it throws:

com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable

and telnet from the server works fine.(i.e telnet exchange-server-name 25)

my properties are :

```
        'Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer );
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");'
```

PS:
1. i tried updating the mail.jar, started TLS(using starttls),
2. tried enabling ssl(i.e props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");) while using port 465.
3. tried setting the smtp type to TLS using port 587.

all suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See the [JavaMail connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug), but it looks like you have a basic networking problem preventing access from your server to the mail server, perhaps because of a firewall.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i already have disabled the firewall on my RHEL server. is there any antivirus(such as symantic end protection)runs on the machine operating for exchange server?? if so can it kill the sending with his heuristic??

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the Exchange server could be preventing you from connecting, although that seems unlikely given the error you're getting.  It's much more likely that the problem is on your application server machine, not on the mail server.  What happened when you tried the connection debugging tips?